# How to remove carriage returns and line feeds from a column?

Tags: mysql, sql, line-breaks, carriage-return

I'm trying to remove carriage returns and line feeds from a column I imported from a csv file.
I'm using the code:

```
SELECT replace(replace(column,CHAR(13),''),CHAR(10),'')
FROM table
```

It correctly finds all the CR and LF, but it doesn't update the database.

Comment: If you want to change the data in the database you need an `UPDATE` query.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your query retrieve from your table named TABLE all rows with the column replaced.

About UPDATE your database you must use UPDATE command in this way:

```
UPDATE table SET column = replace(replace(column,CHAR(13),''),CHAR(10),'')
```

If you want condition the UPDATE about the satisfaction of some conditions, so you must add the WHERE clause.

For example

```
UPDATE table SET column = replace(replace(column,CHAR(13),''),CHAR(10),'')
WHERE column_2 = 'XXX'
```

Comment: Can I just add, I eventually worked out that for *each* table column, you have to add this: So, for mine it was:

SELECT customers.name,replace(replace(monies_in.description,CHAR(13),''),CHAR(10),''),monies_in.date,replace(replace(monies_in.bank_ref,CHAR(13),''),CHAR(10),''),monies_in.amount,monies_in.apos_ref FROM monies_in INNER JOIN customers ON monies_in.payer_id = customers.id  WHERE date BETWEEN "2020-3-31" AND "2021-4-1" INTO OUTFILE '/home/Data/dest/spreadsheets/monies_in.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';

Comment: Probably obvious to most people with more sql experience,. but it took a few minutes for the penny to drop for me!