# DELETE the last character from a row if the last character is char(10) in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database called `dbo.ups_test` and inside I have a column called `address` in which I wrote a script to parse the address apart into address1, 2, 3, 4 etc.

I get all values returned as null if there is a char(10) at the end of an address which is no good.

I am trying to write a Query on dbo.ups_test so that I can remove the `char(10)` from every address that has char(10) as the last character

The code I am currently using to view all of the fields that end in Char(10) that are essentially messing this up is this

```
SELECT *
from ups_import_test
where RIGHT(ds_address, 1) = char(10);
```

This returns all the rows that need to be corrected and have the char(10) removed from the last character.

I understand that data should not be entered in this way and I realize that I don’t have to parse an address if it is input the way I need it.

Comment: edit the question with the dbms being used. i assumed it was sql server.

Comment: the tag i used is SQL server that being said i assumed that was shown to the public...

Answer (score 1):

maybe just use substring?

```
UPDATE  ups_import_test 
SET     ds_address = SUBSTRING(ds_address, 1, LEN(ds_address) - 1)
WHERE   RIGHT(ds_address, 1) = CHAR(10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys i solved the problem by checking to see if the last character in the string was char(10) or char(13) then if it was i used.....

```
UPDATE ups_import_test
SET    ds_address = substring(rtrim(ds_address), 1, len(rtrim(ds_address)) - len(1))
WHERE  RIGHT(ds_address, 1) = char(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should just replace the character before parsing the data

[mysql - removing CHAR(13) CHAR(13)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20577365/mysql-removing-char13-char13)  `SELECT replace(column,CHAR(10),'')
FROM table` - The code above replaces the char(10) with nothing.

Comment: this again would remove all char 10 from the data which was no good. because i was parsing the address block by the char(10) delimiter. the problem was that there was a trailing char(10) that would throw off the parsed data and return null for address1, 2, 3, 4 etc. scaisEdge was correct

Comment: Ah, understood. My apologies - I did not read your question clearly.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
update ups_import_test
    set ds_address = replace(ds_address,char(10),'')
where RIGHT(ds_address, 1) = char(10);
```

Comment: this wouldve removed all char(10) which was not what i needed. i just needed to remove the last character if it was a char(10)

Answer (score 0):

You can use update

```
update ups_import_test 
set ds_address = LEFT(ds_address , CHAR_LENGTH(ds_address  -1)
where RIGHT(ds_address, 1) = char(10);
```